# Render exposed filter without creating block

Tags: 8

Can we place/render exposed filter to some other region(sidebar second) without creating exposed filter in block because when we creating exposed filter with block its autosubmit functionality stopped working ,without creating exposed filter with block its autosubmit functionality working fine.

I am using better exposed filter module https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters.

Comment: I believe if you enable ajax, (under advanced, far right) in views, it will work when as block, but I'm not 100% sure, so just give it a go and see what happens.

Comment: Still Not working ,i think its a big issue with views exposed filter in drupal 8

Comment: By default exposed filter is rendering just above the view result ,i need to place it in sidebar second,its so urgent for me to implement as my client needed the same:(

Comment: Sounds like you were experiencing this problem: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3175725

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. I created a custom block which uses the following code.

```php
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormState;
use Drupal\views\Views;
 
$form = [];
$view_id = 'Your-view-id';
$display_id = 'your-display-id';
$view = Views::getView($view_id);
if ($view) {
  $view->setDisplay($display_id);
  $view->initHandlers();
  $form_state = (new FormState())->setStorage([
    'view' => $view,
    'display' => &$view->display_handler->display,
    'rerender' => TRUE,
  ])
    ->setMethod('get')
    ->setAlwaysProcess()
    ->disableRedirect();
  $form_state->set('rerender', NULL);
  $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->buildForm('\Drupal\views\Form\ViewsExposedForm', $form_state);
  print render($form);
}
```

You can create your own exposed filter in a block without requiring any third-party module.

Comment: Additional discussion: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2017-02-20/how-to-programmatically-render-a-view