# What is the purpose of rerender FormState property?

Tags: 8, views

I am trying to understand [With a taxonomy term view Exposed form in block has incorrect action URL /taxonomy/term/all, not taking into account term id and breaking filtering without AJAX/JS](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3175725) and in the process I see the `rerender` property is mentioned in code a lot, such as on [Render exposed filter without creating block](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/236576/render-exposed-filter-without-creating-block) and [How to programmatically render a view exposed filter inputs with form state maintain?](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2017-02-20/how-to-programmatically-render-a-view) The original problem is that the code runs the second time and it doesn't get view arguments, but I don't see where the `rerender` property can influence this process and how it's reasonably used at all. The only place I see is in an Ajax sub-folder, but I don't have Ajax enabled on my view yet.

What problem does this property solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place in core that checks for, `$form_state->get('rerender')` in an `if` statement is in:

/core/modules/**views_ui**/src/Form/Ajax/ **[ViewsFormBase.php](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/8.9.x/core/modules/views_ui/src/Form/Ajax/ViewsFormBase.php#L129)**

```
// If the form has not been submitted, or was not set for rerendering, stop.
if (!$form_state->isSubmitted() || $form_state->get('rerender')) {
  return $response;
}

// Sometimes we need to re-generate the form for multi-step type operations.
if (!empty($view->stack)) {
  $stack = $view->stack;
  $top = array_shift($stack);

  // Build the new form state for the next form in the stack.
  $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($view::$forms[$top[1]]);
  /** @var $form_state \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface */
  $form_state = $reflection->newInstanceArgs(array_slice($top, 3, 2))->getFormState($view, $top[2], $form_state->get('ajax'));
  $form_class = get_class($form_state->getFormObject());

  $form_state->setUserInput([]);
  $form_url = views_ui_build_form_url($form_state);
  if (!$form_state->get('ajax')) {
    return new RedirectResponse($form_url->setAbsolute()->toString());
  }
  $form_state->set('url', $form_url);
  $response = $this->ajaxFormWrapper($form_class, $form_state);
}
elseif (!$form_state->get('ajax')) {
  // if nothing on the stack, non-js forms just go back to the main view editor.
  $display_id = $form_state->get('display_id');
  return new RedirectResponse(Url::fromRoute('entity.view.edit_display_form', ['view' => $view->id(), 'display_id' => $display_id], ['absolute' => TRUE])->toString());
}
else {
  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $response->addCommand(new CloseModalDialogCommand());
  $response->addCommand(new ShowButtonsCommand(!empty($view->changed)));
  $response->addCommand(new TriggerPreviewCommand());
  if ($page_title = $form_state->get('page_title')) {
    $response->addCommand(new ReplaceTitleCommand($page_title));
  }
}
```

The `if (!empty($view->stack)) {` part will only pass if the form is a multi-step form and you're not in the last step; otherwise, it will proceed to close the modal. Ex: when you click "Apply" or "Cancel" or "Remove". (Ex: when adding a field) it triggers the else:

```
else {
  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $response->addCommand(new CloseModalDialogCommand());
  $response->addCommand(new ShowButtonsCommand(!empty($view->changed)));
  $response->addCommand(new TriggerPreviewCommand());
  if ($page_title = $form_state->get('page_title')) {
    $response->addCommand(new ReplaceTitleCommand($page_title));
  }
}
```

#### Conclusion

As it only gets checked in the views_ui module, this setting is basically a way to tell the **Views UI Form**:

if the setting form is a multi-step form, like when you're adding a field:

[image]

to keep the modal open and build a new `$form_state` for the next form

[image]

Otherwise, its like when you click apply/cancel/remove it tells it to close the modal, show save & cancel buttons, and show/refresh the live preview.